# Someone setup a clone of our company website - why?

Tags: spam

We recently discovered a clone of our website and I've found several mentions of other people having had the same problem [here](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/45528/our-website-has-been-cloned-and-is-now-running-under-a-vn-domain-course-of), [here](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/78404/someone-has-cloned-my-wordpress-blog-how-do-i-prevent-it-from-hurting-seo/78411), and [here](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/65324/parallel-website-running-a-copy-of-my-original-website).  We're taking the necessary steps to have the site taken down so I'm just curious as to what these people are gaining out of spoofing our website.  They even got a DV cert for the domain.

Is it just for SEO and PageRank gains?  Is this a new tactic or something that's been going on for a while?

Forgot to mention: the link to checkout is removed leaving only our "Checkout with PayPal" button, but that still leads to our actual PayPal landing page.  So it doesn't seem that there's anyway someone could pay them money.

Comment: To fool people into thinking they are you and get money from them.

Comment: @Rob, I thought the same thing at first but our "Checkout with PayPal" button still goes to our PayPal landing page and they filter out the standard payment page link.

Comment: I swear this can be a real mystery sometimes. The payoff is not always clear. The very least may be for search traffic to at least begin monetizing the site. Even if there are no ads shown, just getting the ball rolling may be what they are up to. Then after a while, a change may be made to monetize the site be it ads or just plain spam.